# Supertab list options, but do NOT auto select

Tags: vim, code-completion, supertab

Is there anyway to configure Supertab, the VIM plugin, so that when I enter a portion of code, and hit tab I can continue typing while narrowing down the suggestions?

For Example in java:

```
System.out.pr<tab>
```

Should show a list of options (print, printf, println), but
the text should remain

```
System.out.pr
```

That is until I hit enter to make a selection.

Also is it possible to see the options, but continue typing to narrow them down?

For Example in c:

```
pu<tab>
```

displays lots of options (putc, putc_unlocked, puts, etc)

but as soon as I've hit tab SuperTab highlights the highest option and puts that text there, so I'm left to cycle through the remaining options to choose what I want. Would it be possible to just show the menu of options, but continue typing and see the options change as I type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just looking for this:

```
set completeopt=menu,longest    " Use the popup menu by default; only insert the longest common text of the completion matches; don't automatically show extra information in the preview window.
```

This is already mentioned in the SuperTab help. Also of interest may be the related `g:SuperTabLongestHighlight` option.